# Functional Analysis: A question about boundary.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, compact-operators

Here is the question:

> Let be $X$ a real normed vector space and $ \varphi : X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ linear. Show that if $\varphi$ is unbounded then for all $\delta$, $ \varphi (B(0, \delta)) = \mathbb{R}$ ( the image of the open ball with center zero and radius delta ).

I tried to answer for contraposition, i.e, I wanna show that $\varphi$ is bounded. Here is my draft:

> I supposed that it exists a $\delta$ such that $ \varphi (B(0, \delta)) \neq  \mathbb{R}.$ Thus, exists an $a \in   \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\xi \in B(o, \delta) $ one have $ \varphi (\xi) \neq a $. Then $ \varphi (\xi) > a $ or $ \varphi (\xi) < a .$

But I can't finish this question. Can Someone help me?
I will be very grateful.

Comment: When you write “ilimited”, do you mean “unbounded”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes! I got confused.

Comment: By scaling it is enough to show that $\varphi(B(0,1))=\mathbb{R}$. Note that by linearity we have that $\varphi(B(0,1)) = (-R,R)$ where $R\in \mathbb{R}$. However, if $R<\infty$, then $\varphi$ is bounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven When I suppose that $ \varphi B(0,1)) = (-R, R),$ Do I using continuity ?

Comment: Only linearity, or actually homogeneity. If $\phi(x)=r\neq0$ for some $x$, then you can get any value $t\in(-r,r)$ as $\phi(\frac{t}{r}x)=\frac{t}{r}\phi(x)=t$.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically done. If there exist $\xi,\eta\in B(0,\delta)$ with $\varphi(\xi)>a$ and $\varphi(\eta)<a$, then there exists $t\in(0,1)$ with $a=t\varphi(\xi)+(1-t)\varphi(\eta)$ (that is, $a$ is in the segment that joins $\varphi(\xi)$ and $\varphi(\eta)$. Then $\nu=t\xi+(1-t)\eta\in B(0,\delta)$ and
$$
\varphi(\nu)=a,
$$
a contradiction. So either $\varphi(\xi)>a$ for all $\xi\in B(0,\delta)$, or $\varphi(\xi)<a$ for all $\xi$. In the first case, we may rewrite the inequality as $\varphi(-\xi)<-a$, and since $0\in B(0,\delta)$ we get $0<-a$. Thus $$ |\varphi(\xi)|<-a$$ for all $\xi\in B(0,\delta)$. In the second case, we get $0<a$ and $|\varphi(\xi)|<a$ for all $\xi\in B(0,\delta)$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think to use the fact $0 \in \varphi (B(0, \delta))$